# Group by, sort and sort the group in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have data as below and want to apply group by, sort within the group and finally sort the group.

```
1.2   5
1.3   5
1.5   4
2.1   4
2.2   4
3.5   4
```

By using java 8 collections, i want to group by second column data and sort first column data.
Later, I want to sort the groups it self.

Below is the data that I expected

```
1.3   5
1.2   5
3.5   4
2.2   4
2.1   4
1.5   4
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I created a separate object for each group, and that object holds first column data as a list. That list is sorted. Finally group objects are sorted. So If i iterate group list i get the data as expected. But is there any simple way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to run the below single line method to sort it as you need

```
public static void sortGroup(List<Group> list) {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Group::getCol2)
                        .thenComparing(Group::getCol1)
                        .reversed());
}
```

- Here `list` is the `List<Group>`.
- We use `Compartors` to order `col2` and then `col1` in ascending order. Finally `reversed()` reverses the total order.

---

I have assumed the `Group` to be structured as

```
private static class Group {
        double col1;
        int col2;

        public Group(double col1, int col2) {
            this.col1 = col1;
            this.col2 = col2;
        }

        public double getCol1() {
            return col1;
        }

        public int getCol2() {
            return col2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return col1 + "\t" + col2;
        }
    }
```

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Group> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Group(1.2, 5),
            new Group(1.3, 5),
            new Group(1.5, 4),
            new Group(2.1, 4),
            new Group(2.2, 4),
            new Group(3.5, 4));
    sortGroup(list);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.3 5
1.2 5
3.5 4
2.2 4
2.1 4
1.5 4
```